# compile successfully in console but errors occur after importing into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

i have downloaded the source code for project [deeplearning4j](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j) and compiled successfully by the console in fedora. but when i import the project in eclipse, it prompts many errors and all errors are like this "method XXX is undefined for the type YYY". i feel so painful since it has take me some days to compile the source code in the console

Answer (score 0):

If only you'd be a bit more verbose with the error message you cite - it would make a difference if YYY starts with `java.lang` or `org.deeplearning4j` or another package.

If it's `java.lang`: Check if the source compatibility matches the JRE you're using. From deeplearning4j's pom.xml it looks like it's Java7 compatible and it might be worth checking eclipse's compatibility-level for the java compiler. Also try to use a JDK7 instead of crosscompiling on Java8.

Lastly, it might make more sense to get in contact with the authors of the project directly - they'll know a lot better what to do. At least, they say in their [README.md](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/README.md):

> If you feel uncomfortable or uncertain about an issue or your changes,
>   don't hesitate to contact us on Gitter using the link above

and they give a gitter link and chat.

Comment: Thanks and the type begin with org.deeplearning4j. i am using java 8 and it seems fine since i have compile project nd4j,canova and deeplearning4j succefully in console

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the jdk in eclipse perhaps you run 1.8 on your computer but 1.5 with this project in your eclipse  you can see it in your project`s property

Comment: Thanks. $ java -version and it is  

openjdk version "1.8.0_45"  

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)  

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)  

Window-Preferences-Java-Compiler and it is 1.8   

but the JRE System Library is JavaSE-1.7 in the project

Comment: i have change the version of the jdk to 1.7 in eclipse and rebuild the project but it doesn't work